# DataContext, DependencyProperties and Bindings

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

I have a UserControl, we'll call it "Header". It has a DependencyProperty called ProjectID, this control has a  View Model and I set it to be the DataContext:

```
public BillingInfoHeaderControlVM VM
{
    get
    {
        return (BillingInfoHeaderControlVM)DataContext;
    }
    set
    {
        DataContext = value;
    }

}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ProjectIDProperty =
                        DependencyProperty.Register("ProjectID", typeof(int), typeof(BillingInfoHeaderControl), new PropertyMetadata();

public int ProjectID
{
    set
    {
        SetValue(ProjectIDProperty, value);
    }
    get
    {
        return (int)GetValue(ProjectIDProperty);
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do, is to bind the ProjectID of a control to this control's ProjectID:

```
<controls:Header Grid.Row ="0" x:Name="Header" ProjectID="{Binding ProjectID, Mode=OneWay}"></controls:Header>
```

Now when I run this, I get an error in the InitializeControl() method that states "

> Property Get method was not found.

From what I'm reading, I'm seeing this is because the Binding ProjectID is relative to the data context of the control. Of course I could set the ElementName within the binding:

```
<controls:Header Grid.Row ="0" x:Name="Header" ProjectID="{Binding ProjectID, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=ParentControl}"></controls:Header>
```

But this is ugly, and to be honest we don't want to have to remember to do this for this control whenever we use it. What other options do I have? Is there a way to set the source of the binding to use the DataContext of the parent?

Comment: The ProjectID is not also a property of the ViewModel?  If not, why not, that is the role for the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I duplicated your concept in code and it compiles and runs fine.

I have included the control code and the viewmodel below in case you are doing something different.

*Note: I kept the viewmodel ProjectID as a simple update property.:

```
namespace Demo1
{
    public partial class BillingInfoHeaderControl : UserControl
    {
        public BillingInfoHeaderControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new BillingInfoHeaderControlVM();
        }

        public int ProjectId
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ProjectIdProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ProjectIdProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ProjectIdProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ProjectId", typeof(int), typeof(BillingInfoHeaderControl),
              new PropertyMetadata(0));

    }
}

namespace Demo1
{
    public class BillingInfoHeaderControlVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _projectId;
        public int ProjectId
        {
            get { return _projectId; }
            set
            {
                if (_projectId != value)
                {
                    _projectId = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProjectId"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: But if you include this UserControl into a different control, and bind something from the parent's control to this control's property, that's when I would expect to see the error.

So what we're dealing with is that the Parent Control (let's call this the MainView) has its own VM and own datacontext. It's we then want to bind the MainView.VM.CurrentProjectID to Header.ProjectID:

`<MainView><controls:Header Grid.Row ="0" x:Name="Header" ProjectID="{Binding CurrentProjectID, Mode=OneWay}"></controls:Header></MainView>`

Where CurrentProjectID is a member of the MainView's VM.

Comment: @Timothy Baldridge: I created a fuller example as you suggested using a viewmodel on the main window etc and it also works correctly. Can you post more code & Xaml? It is likely a very simple fault.